# Set a callback function inside a javascript class

Tags: javascript, class, callback

excuse the pseudo code, my actual file is much larger:/

I want to call a function (with parameters) from inside a class. However, that function should be passed to the class as a variable.

```
someObject = {
    itWorked:function(answer){
       alert(answer);
    },

    plugins:{
        somePlugin:function(){

            var callback;
            this.doSomething = doSomething;

            function setCallback(c){
                callback = c;
            }

            function doSomething(){
                 var answer = "hello";
                 [callback](answer); // how do I call this?
            }

        }
    },

    widgets:{
        something:function(){
            var doIt = new someObject();
            doIt.setCallback(someObject.itWorked()); // how do I send this?
            doIt.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

So how would I pass `itWorked()` to the class?
And how would I call that `itWorked(answer)` function within the class as well as passing a variable to if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses to pass the function as a variable.

```
doIt.setCallback( someObject.itWorked );
```

You can then use the callback as you would any other function.

```
callback( answer );
```

Comment: Good answer here, I just posted an alternative implementation, but there is nothing wrong with this one.

Comment: You should also check if the callback exists, and is an executable function: `if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {}`

Answer (score 3):

You will need to change

```
setCallback = function (c) {callback = c;}
```

to

```
this.setCallback =  function (c) {callback = c;}
```

so the setCallback function will be public.

If you also want to scope the callback, you can call it like this

```
callback.call(scope, param1, param2);
```

If you don't know how many parameters, you can call it like this

```
callback.apply(scope, parameters);
```

Scope could be any object, even an empty one {} if you want.

By the way, I really like your use of private variables in this example, great work with the javascript.  Here is a good way to write your javascript object to help with the initialization and readability

```
var mynamespace = {};

(function () {
   function MyObject(param1, param2) {
      this.initialize(param1, param2);
   }

   MyObject.prototype = {
      initialize: function (param1, param2) {
          var privateScope = {
              param1: param1,
              param2: param2,
              callback: null
          };

          this.setCallback = function (c) {
              privateScope.callback = c;
          }

          this.doSomething = function () {
              if (privateScope.callback) {
                  privateScope.callback.call();
              }
          }
      }
   }
   mynamespace.MyObject = MyObject;
}());
```

Then to use it

```
var obj = new mynamespace.MyObject("value1", "value2");
```

Comment: thanks :) I'm a bit of a js noob at this level, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Well you are off to a great start, this is well written javascript.

Comment: do you know if there is a __construct() equivalent for javascript? So rather than call ```doIt.setCallback(someObject.itWorked)``` pass it in at the ```new someObject()``` stage?

Comment: @ed209, the function `someObject` is the constructor function. Functions act as constructors when used with `new`

Comment: Check this doc about [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: @Esailija ok, makes sense. want to thin down the code to pass the callback on ```new someObj(someObject.itWorked)```

Comment: I updated my answer with a full object implementation that works well for me.